# Long constructors, inheritance, class method constructors

Tags: python, constructor, python-2.x

My class takes functions as a parameter.  There are 6 of them, along with numerous other parameters.  Almost all of the fields have default values.

It also has a class method that creates an instance of the class with 2 of the fields initialized randomly.  It has a subclass that cheats a bit by making 2 of the functions passed in as a parameter unnecessary.

All of this has a lot of redundant information.  I have found bugs in my code caused by mistakes in the constructor calls because they were so long.  I indeed found another while writing this question.

How can I improve this?

#### ParentClass

```
class NeuralNet:
def __init__(self,
             weights,
             biases,
             learning_rate=0.01,
             momentum=0.9, #Set to zero to nut use mementum
             post_process=lambda i: i, #Post Process is applied to final output only (Not used when training), but is used when checkign error rate
             topErrorFunc=squaredMean, d_topErrorFunc=dSquaredMean,
             actFunc=sigmoid, d_actFunc=dSigmoid,
             topActFunc = sigmoid, d_topActFunc = dSigmoid):

    self.weights = weights
    self.biases = biases

    assert len(self.biases)==len(self.weights), "Must have as many bias vectors as weight matrixes"

    self._prevDeltaWs = [np.zeros_like(w) for w in self.weights]
    self._prevDeltaBs = [np.zeros_like(b) for b in self.biases]

    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.post_process = post_process
    self.topErrorFunc = topErrorFunc
    self.d_topErrorFunc = d_topErrorFunc
    self.actFunc = actFunc
    self.d_actFunc=d_actFunc
    self.topActFunc = topActFunc
    self.d_topActFunc = d_topActFunc

@classmethod
def random_init(cls,
                layer_sizes,
                learning_rate=0.01,
                momentum=0.9, #Set to zero to nut use mementum
                post_process=lambda i: i, #Post Process is applied to final output only (Not used when training), but is used when checkign error rate
                topErrorFunc=squaredMean, d_topErrorFunc=dSquaredMean,
                actFunc=sigmoid, d_actFunc=dSigmoid,
                topActFunc=sigmoid, d_topActFunc=dSigmoid):

    weights = [np.random.normal(0,0.01,(szNext,szThis)) for (szThis,szNext) in pairwise(layer_sizes)]
    biases = [np.random.normal(0,0.01,sz) for sz in layer_sizes[1:]]
    return cls(weights, biases, learning_rate, momentum, post_process, topErrorFunc, d_topErrorFunc, actFunc, d_actFunc, topActFunc,d_topActFunc)

#... Class methods
```

#### Subclass

```
class FixedTopErrorSignalNeuralNet(NeuralNet):
    def __init__(self,
                 weights,
                 biases,
                 learning_rate=0.01,
                 momentum=0.9, #Set to zero to nut use mementum
                 post_process=lambda i: i, #Post Process is applied to final output only (Not used when training), but is used when checkign error rate
                 actFunc=sigmoid, d_actFunc=dSigmoid,
                 topActFunc = softmax, d_topActFunc = dSoftmax):
        NeuralNet.__init__(self,
                           weights=weights,
                           biases=biases,
                           momentum=momentum,
                           post_process=post_process,
                           topErrorFunc=None, d_topErrorFunc=None,
                           actFunc=actFunc, d_actFunc=d_actFunc,
                           topActFunc=topActFunc, d_topActFunc=d_topActFunc)

    @classmethod
    def random_init(cls,
                    layer_sizes,
                    learning_rate=0.01,
                    momentum=0.9, #Set to zero to nut use mementum
                    post_process=lambda i: i, #Post Process is applied to final output only (Not used when training), but is used when checkign error rate
                    actFunc=sigmoid, d_actFunc=dSigmoid,
                    topActFunc=softmax, d_topActFunc=dSoftmax):

        weights = [np.random.normal(0,0.01,(szNext,szThis)) for (szThis,szNext) in pairwise(layer_sizes)]
        biases = [np.random.normal(0,0.01,sz) for sz in layer_sizes[1:]]
        return cls(weights, biases, learning_rate, momentum, post_process, actFunc, d_actFunc, topActFunc,d_topActFunc)

 #... Overrides etc
```

#### What the parameters do

It has been suggested that this class is doing too many things, because of its large number of parameters. Here are what they do, which may provide insight.

The functional parameters are mostly there to avoid hard-coding them in.  They are all very simple mathematical (pure) 1-2 liners.

- `actFunc` is a mathematical activation function
- `d_actFunc` is its derivative
- `top_actFunc` is a alternative activation function used at the top of the neural net (very common technique)
- `d_top_actFunc` is its derivative
- `ErrorFunc` is used to calculate the error for during training
- `d_errorFunc` is its derivative
- `post_process` is simple mathematical transform used to get the final output, when used on nontraining data

They are all parameters of the model.

One alternative could be that rather than passing them in as a parameter, I make them abstract methods, and then for each variation I could override them.  This doesn't feel right to me, though something like [Java's anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) might work.

Comment: [I know nothing of python](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/lol-upvote?tab=tags&sort=votes), but in other languages having a class with lots of constructor parameters is often a sign our object is breaking SRP and basically *does too many things*.

Comment: I don't think it is breakign the SRP, as it has one responsibility, being a neural-net. It is just highly parametrised.

Comment: Well +1 anyway, looks like a good CR question... the code works right?

Comment: It does. and indeed (/however) even with the terrible constructor bugs i had, it still worked because neural nets are super fault tolerant, so i was usign the wrong derivative and it was just fine...

Answer (score 6):

There's three ways I could see this going.

#### stronger hierarchy

Create what amounts to an abstract base class for NeuralNet with stubs for the math functions and then make subclasses to override the methods.

```
class NeuralNetBase(object):
    def __init__(self, biases, learning_rate=0.01,  momentum=0.9):
        self.weights = weights
        self.biases = biases

        assert len(self.biases)==len(self.weights), "Must have as many bias vectors as weight matrixes"

       self._prevDeltaWs = [np.zeros_like(w) for w in self.weights]
       self._prevDeltaBs = [np.zeros_like(b) for b in self.biases]
       self.learning_rate = learning_rate
       self.momentum = momentum

   def act_func(self):
       raise NotImplemented
   def d_act_func(self):
       raise NotImplemented
   def top_act_func(self):
       raise NotImplemented
   def d_top_act_func(self):
       raise NotImplemented


class SigmoidNeuralNet(NeuralNetBase):
   
   def act_func(self):
       # magic here
   def d_act_func(self):
       # more magic
   def top_act_func(self):
       # even more...           
   def d_top_act_func(self):
       # like hogwarts!
```

This would work well if there is a high correlation between the optional functions: if they tend to cluster together they'd make a natural class hierarchy (and you'd have an easy way to see which nodes were using which function sets just by looking at their concrete classes).  OTOH this won't work well if the functions are not correlated.

#### Kwargs to the rescue

You can simplify the constructor logic by using kwargs and by including the defaults in the **init** method (for sanity's sake I'd move the pure data into required parameters, but that's just aesthetics);

```
class NeuralNet(object):
    def __init__(self, biases, learning_rate,  momentum, **kwargs):
        self.weights = weights
        self.biases = biases

        assert len(self.biases)==len(self.weights), "Must have as many bias vectors as weight matrixes"

       self._prevDeltaWs = [np.zeros_like(w) for w in self.weights]
       self._prevDeltaBs = [np.zeros_like(b) for b in self.biases]
       self.learning_rate = learning_rate
       self.momentum = momentum

       # assuming the default implementations 'private' class methods 
       # defined below
       self.act = kwargs.get('act_func', self._default_act_func)
       self.top_act = kwargs.get('top_act_func', self._default_top_act_func)
       self.d_act = kwargs.get('d_act_func', self._default_d_act_func)
       self.d_top_act_func = kwargs.get('top_d_act_func', self._default_d_top_act_func)
       self.postprocess = kwags.get('post', self._default_postprocess)
```

### function components

If a lot of reasoning goes into the choice or relationship of the functions, you could just put them all into an object and work with those objects instead of loose funcs:

```
  class NeuralNet(object):
    def __init__(self, biases, learning_rate,  momentum, funcs = DefaultFuncs):
        self.weights = weights
        self.biases = biases
         #... etc
        self.Functions = funcs(self)

  class DefaultFFuncs(object):
     def __init__(self, target, act_func, top_func, d_act_func, d_top_func);
         self.Target = target
         self._act_func = act_func
         self._act_func = act_func
         self._d_top_func = d_top_func
         self._d_top_func = d_top_func

   def act_func(self):
       return self._act_func(self.Target)

   def d_act_func(self):
       return self._d_act_func(self.Target)

   def top_act_func(self):
       return self._top_act_func(self.Target)

   def d_top_act_func(self):
       return self._d_top_act_func(self.Target)
```

This would let you compose and reuse a collection of funcs into a DefaultFuncs and then reuse it -- default funcs is really just an elaborate Tuple tricked out so you can call into the functions from the owning NeuralNet instance

All of these are functionally identical approaches (it sounds like you've already got the thing working and just want to clean it up).  The main reasons for choosing among them amount to where you want to put the work  #1 is good if the functions correlate and you want to easily tell when a given net instance is using a set; #2 is just syntax sugar on what you've already got; #3 is really just #2 except that you compose a function set as class (perhaps with error checking or more sophisticated reasoning) instead of a a dictionary

Comment: This is a great answer, useful to consider in many contexts.   Bundling args into a helper class, using base/subs, etc.   I like.

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions:

1. You can simplify `random_init` as: `def random_init(self, **kwargs):`; this allows you to pass any provided arguments straight through to `return cls(weights, biases, **kwargs)` without explicitly specifying them. This prevents the current duplication of default values, which could lead to problems if you change one and forget to change the other.
2. `random_init` in `FixedTopErrorSignalNeuralNet` appears identical to that in `NeuralNet`, so just use the inherited version; don't define it again.
3. More broadly, `FixedTopErrorSignalNeuralNet` appears to only provide two different arguments to the `NeuralNet.__init__` (note: should access this via `super(FixedTopErrorSignalNeuralNet, self).__init__`); unless it has different methods, too, you could just use another `@classmethod` to create this variant. Again, you could use `**kwargs` to reduce duplication.
4. Could you pass only the standard functions (e.g. `actFunc`) then differentiate them locally? That would save passing pairs of functions.

Comment: Re Point 3: FixedTopErrorSignalNeuralNet, has other methods, (as to does NeuralNet) not show.

Comment: Re 4. No It is not worth integrating a CAS system just to skip out on a few arguments. CAS systems would stuggle with the differentiation.

Comment: Re Super: I though super was not to be used in python 2,
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/5066411/179081